# Call method with implicit argument where type is only known at runtime

Tags: scala, reflection, implicits

Say I have a method like this:

```
def doSomething(a : A)(implicit someTrait : SomeTrait[A]) : B = { ... }
```

I call a Java method that gives me an `AnyRef` back and I want to pass the returned object to `doSomething`:

```
val obj : AnyRef = javaObject.getRef
doSomething(obj)
```

I have enough information at runtime to get a more specific type `T` for the `AnyRef` object. I am certain that there will be `SomeTrait[T]` for whatever type `T` I find at runtime.

How can I call `doSomething` on the `AnyRef`? Can I look up the `SomeTrait[T]` at runtime somehow and pass it explicitly?

I do not care if this potentially blows up at runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In principle you cannot. Implicit resolution happens at compile time.

If you can enumerate over `SomeTrait`, you can of course do something with a pattern match, like

```
trait SomeTrait[A]
implicit object SomeIntTrait    extends SomeTrait[Int]
implicit object SomeStringTrait extends SomeTrait[String]

def doSomething[A: SomeTrait](a: A) = ???

def atRuntime(x: Any) = x match {
  case i: Int    => doSomething[Int](i)
  case s: String => doSomething[String](s)
}
```